# Как поймать неправильное отключение клиента от WCF службы?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

Сценарий:

Юзер сидит в клиенте и закрывает его через ctrl+alt+del.

При первом обращении к методу службы я делаю это:

```
            if (channel == null)
        {
            channel = OperationContext.Current.Channel;
            channel.Closed += UnlockDictionary;
            channel.Faulted += UnlockDictionary;
            Dictionary_id = dictionary_id;
        }
```

И событие срабатывает на стороне службы, например при выходе за контекст using на клиенте.

Однако, если юзер делает ctrl+alt+del, то в это событие я не попадаю, хотя юзер вызывал один из методов=> ссылка на канал сохранена.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Существует два варианта:

1. Реализовать самостоятельно некоторое подобие механизма "Ping", т.е. клиент должен регулярно вызывать метод сервера и если сервер не получил вовремя запрос от клиента, то считать что клиент отсоединился.
   Если у вас двунаправленный binding, то можно сделать обратное - вызывать с сервера клиент и как только получите исключение - значит клиент пропал.
2. Включить reliable session на уровне binding и выставить inactivityTimeout. Инфраструктура reliable session посылает такие Ping запросы с периодом половина inactivityTimeout. Вот тут (правда, на англ. SO) более подробно: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26732515/keepalive-with-wcf-and-tcp