# Взаимодействие конечных точек WCF между собой

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

Есть WCF служба. В этой службе имеется несколько конечных точек с разными возможностями.
Одна точка дает доступ к данным, а через другую производится загрузка файлов.

Разумеется приходится создавать 2 разных прокси.

Когда клиент получает данные, но в базе прописывается признак Locked, который не позволяет получить доступ других пользователей к этим данным на время редактирования. Так же вешается событие на Closed и Fault, что бы данные не остались заблокированными при непридвиденных обстоятельствах.

Может ли одна конечная точка сообщить другой, что нужно произвести первой точке отписку от событий?

Сейчас данная логика описывается на стороне клиента. Правильно ли это?

Comment: По идее, блокировки должны быть краткосрочными, поэтому при нормальных обстоятельствах достаточно просто дождаться получения блокировки. У вас блокировка длинная?

Comment: @VladD. Пользователь получает данные и данные специально блокируются на время, пока пользователь с ними работает. В БД ставится признак Locked и WCF служба не выдает их другим пользователям. Проблема в том, можно ли на стороне службы, сообщить из одной точке другой:"Теперь я занимаюсь этими данными, пожалуйста не переводи их в состояние Avalible при отсоединении клиента.". Сейчас я отсылаю запрос с клиента, что необходимо отписаться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант, можно сделать блокировку с подсчетом ссылок - одному и тому же пользователю разрешено блокировать записи любое число раз, блокировка снимается при отключении всех сессий.

В БД при этом понадобятся поля LockedBy (имя пользователя, захватившего блокировку) и LockCount.

Comment: Думаю, что ваше решение наиболее верное и компактное. С помощью него в событии на закрытие подключение можно задать дополнительное условие, что LockedBy должен быть равен юзеру в контексте. Если там Null, то осуществился перехват другой службой и менять статусы ненужно, так как об этом позаботится другая точка.

Comment: А как при этом обрабатывается сценарий «юзер залочил базу и ушёл обедать/свалил домой/уехал в отпуск»? (Это не подколка, я серьёзно интересуюсь.)

Comment: @VladD, Ну это можно решить какими-нибудь таймаутами. Вроде что-то такое можно задать в конфигурации WCF.

Comment: @VladD вырубаем его комп - и сессия отваливается по тайм-ауту

Comment: @VladD если юзер на удаленке - просим админа прибить сессию VPN

Comment: @PavelMayorov: То есть надо держать открытое соединение, правильно? Или пинговать подсоединённого клиента время от времени?

Comment: @VladD это был один из прошлых вопросов этого автора :) У WCF есть встроенная функциональность, ее надо только настроить.

Comment: Это: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/510590?

Comment: @iluxa1810: Понял, спасибо.